# fetch data using two implode values in php

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

Hi am trying fetch value from database with matched value in 1 column,

my table:

```
╔════╦═══════════════╦═══════╗
║ id ║  Community    ║ name  ║
╠════╬═══════════════╬═══════╣
║  1 ║ Jeff, Atwood  ║ test1 ║
║  2 ║ Geoff Dalgas  ║ test2 ║
╚════╩═══════════════╩═══════╝
```

my sql statment

```
    $testvalue = 'Jeff, Dalgas';
    foreach ($testvalue as $key) {
         $this->query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE Community LIKE :key");
         $this->bind(':key', '%'.$key.'%');
         $row3 = $this->resultSet();
var_dump($row3);
    }
```

its checking first value only its not printing second value in `$testvalue` i want check each value in `$testvalue` if match with column fetch details

Comment: You want to search for Jeff and dalgas in each iteration?

Comment: `$testvalue = 'jeff, dalgas';` isn't an array of values, `$testvalue =[ 'jeff', 'dalgas'];`

Comment: Also you have to careful with 'jeff' != 'Jeff' as the capital is different

Comment: am trying to check like this 1) first i want check 'Jeff' value if it match print the user details, 2) second check 'Dalgas' if it match print the user details,

Comment: No there is no need for that @NigelRen Small or Capital doesn't matter.

Comment: Why unticked and deleted comment on my answer? @NayeshDaggula

Comment: @prit.patel, I say about being careful as sometimes the case is important.  This will find it even if the case is different, which may not be what OP wants.

Comment: sorry. i tried with this $testvalue = array('jeff', 'dalgas'); in foreach{} but its checking first value only not second value,  am trying to print if first value match with community column and check second value print

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$testvalue = array('jeff', 'dalgas');
```

Comment: am trying to check like this 1) first i want check 'Jeff' value if it match print the user details, 2) second check 'Dalgas' if it match print the user details,

Comment: So this will do this as your `$testvalue` isn'a an array to foreach on.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but maybe you can try

```
    $testvalue = explode(",", 'Jeff, Dalgas');
    $conditions = $parameters = $parameters_type = array();

    foreach ($testvalue as $key) {
        $conditions[] = ' FIND_IN_SET(?, "Community") ';
        $parameters[] = $key;
        $parameters_type[] = 's';
    }

    $where = implode(" OR ", $conditions);

    $this->query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE $where ");
    $parameters_type = implode("",$parameters_type);
    $this->bind_param($parameters_type, $parameters);
    $row3 = $this->resultSet();
```